# Is it possible to reuse Java trusted certificates for javax.ws.rs (Resteasy implementation)?

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy

Suppose we need to trust a self-signed SSL certificate. As an example, let's use https://self-signed.badssl.com/.

Since the signer is not a "proper" authority, Java doesn't trust it and refuses to connect to that server. However, after

```
$ cd $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security
$ keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias ... -file ... -keystore cacerts
```

and restart of the application, the following code works:

```
new URL ("https://self-signed.badssl.com/").openConnection ().getResponseCode ()
```

and returns 200 (OK), without throwing an exception.  I.e. basic Java way of opening an HTTPS connection now works, since the certificate is now trusted.

However, this doesn't have any visible effect on javax.ws.rs Client (as implemented in Resteasy, at least) and I still get an exception:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Unable to invoke request
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:287)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:407)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocationBuilder.method(ClientInvocationBuilder.java:273)
        [...]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1506)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:535)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:403)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:283)
        ... 90 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1488)
        ... 107 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
        ... 113 more
```

It seems as Resteasy doesn't take "standard" keystore into account.  But I would rather like to have a central (machine-specific) place for additional trusted keys and not bother how exactly application uses them, with `URL.openConnection` or javax.ws.rs.

**Question**
Is it possible to make javax.ws.rs `Client` use *the same* keystore as "normal" Java HTTPS connection mechanism?

Comment: Please let me know if my answer works for you.

Comment: Sure, it's just not trivial to implement and I'm busy with other tasks right now. A question: currently I don't depend on any particular implementation, so at compilation time I only have the interfaces available. How would I compile against Resteasy, not just have it supplied at runtime by the webserver?

Comment: My current answer is tailored to RESTEasy because your questions mentions your are using RESTEasy as JAX-RS implementation. In order to use `ResteasyClientBuilder`, you will need to add the [`resteasy-client`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-client) dependency. You can add that dependency as `provided` scope if you are using a container that provides RESTEasy, such as WildFly.

Comment: Well, if you have an answer that is implementation-independent, that would be even better, of course. We use Gradle, which lacks provided scope for dependencies. What would happen if we have our own Resteasy inside the application? Will it be just preferred to what Wildfly provides?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I am not aware of any implementation independent solution. The key point here is to have the `ResteasyClientBuilder` in your classpath. It can come from your RESTEasy or from the RESTEasy provided by WildFly.

Comment: For some reason, setting the `SSLContext` in the `ClientBuilder` won't work for RESTEasy: `Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(createSSLContext()).build();`. But it works when using `ResteasyClientBuilder`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into it when I have time.

Comment: Please check my update. `SSLContext.getDefault()` will make things simpler. But there might be a bug in RESTEasy. The following instruction works for Jersey but doesn't work for RESTEasy: `Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(SSLContext.getDefault()).build();`.

Comment: Have you tried to configure the truststore of WildFly ? see https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Detailed+Configuration#DetailedConfiguration-%7B%7B%3Ctruststore%2F%3E%7D%7D

Comment: No. I tried now, adding `<truststore path="<...>/java/jre/lib/security/cacerts" keystore-password="..."/>`, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. I tried on both "ManagementRealm" and "ApplicationRealm". Or does it have to be a separate keystore?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Setting the SSL context when creating the `Client` instance

In the [`ClientBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.html) API there's a [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.html#sslContext-javax.net.ssl.SSLContext-) that allows you to set the [`SSLContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html):

> [**`public abstract ClientBuilder sslContext(SSLContext sslContext)`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.html#sslContext-javax.net.ssl.SSLContext-)
>
> Set the SSL context that will be used when creating secured transport connections to server endpoints from web targets created by the client instance that is using this SSL context. The SSL context is expected to have all the security infrastructure initialized, including the key and trust managers.
>
> Setting a SSL context instance resets any key store or trust store values previously specified.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> `sslContext` - secure socket protocol implementation which acts as a factory for secure socket factories or SSL engines. Must not be `null`.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> an updated client builder instance.
>
> **Throws:**
>
> `NullPointerException` - in case the `sslContext` parameter is `null`.

Assuming you have added the certificate to `cacerts` trust store, you could use the default [`SSLContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html) when creating your [`Client`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html) instance.

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(SSLContext.getDefault()).build();
```

It *should* be enough. However, for some reason, the above piece of code does not work with RESTEasy, but does work with Jersey. It's very likely it's a RESTEasy bug.

### The standard solution does not work with RESTEasy. What should I do?

The RESTEasy [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.13.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html#transport_layer) states the following:

> Network communication between the client and server is handled in RESTEasy, by default, by `HttpClient` (4.x) from the Apache HttpComponents project. [...]
>
> RESTEasy and `HttpClient` make reasonable default decisions so that it is possible to use the client framework without ever referencing `HttpClient`, but for some applications it may be necessary to drill down into the `HttpClient` details. [...]

To customize the [`HttpClient`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) used by RESTEeasy, do the following:

```java
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                                         .setSslcontext(SSLContext.getDefault())
                                         .build();

ApacheHttpClient4Engine engine = new ApacheHttpClient4Engine(httpClient);
Client client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().httpEngine(engine).build();
```

Then you can perform the request:

```java
Response response = client.target("https://self-signed.badssl.com/").request().get();
System.out.println(response.getStatus());
```

### Are there any alternatives to the SSL context?

Instead of using the [`SSLContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html) when creating your [`Client`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html), you could load a [`KeyStore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html). To load `cacerts` trust store, you can do the following:

```java
String filename = System.getProperty("java.home") + 
        "/lib/security/cacerts".replace('/', File.separatorChar);
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename);
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
String password = "changeit";
keystore.load(is, password.toCharArray());
```

The `cacerts`' default password is `changeit`.

Then create your [`Client`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html) instance using one of the following approaches:

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().trustStore(keystore).build();
```

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().keyStore(keystore, password).build();
```

The issue is that it doesn't work with RESTEasy, but does work with Jersey.

---

The solutions mentioned above were tested against the following JAX-RS Client API implementations:

- [`jersey-client`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client/2.23.1) (version 2.23.1)
- [`resteasy-client`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-client/3.0.18.Final) (version 3.0.18.Final)

Comment: It works, but unfortunately not on Resteasy 4.2 (Wildfly 8) which we still use on production, because there is no `HttpClientBuilder` in that version. On later versions (e.g. in Wildfly 9) it does make REST clients trust certificates in standard Java keystore. In general, looks like a bug in Resteasy. I had tried the standard solution before asking this question, but it failed on Resteasy, so I thought it was somehow wrong — but it's correct and works on other implementations.

Comment: @doublep What do you mean with *Resteasy 4.2*?

Comment: Eh, not Resteasy, but Apache HttpComponents, sorry.

Comment: I am using this [ ClientBuilder.newBuilder().keyStore(keystore, password).build();] the keystore get in the httpresponse(in different format), but i can make the keystore again from the http response, can you plz help me out this.@cassiomolin