# How to make Jersey ignore ssl certificate error?

Tags: jersey, ssl-certificate, apache-httpclient-4.x

**Error Trace :**

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target##
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:287)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:252)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:701)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:697)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:420)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:316)
at com.xxx.rest.RestClient.execRequest(RestClient.java:49)
at com.xxx.RestClientTest.test(RestClientTest.java:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:394)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:285)
... 36 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
... 51 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
... 57 more
```

Like all other client like apache httpclient, by default, Jersey checks SSL certificate, which is correct way. But in some cases, like development phase, highly probability is that we don't have CA trusted SSL certificate. So question is, how can we make Jersey ignore SSL certificate error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please note that *trusting all certificates is **extremely risky***. *Be careful when doing it*.

The following piece of code is not much different from the one shown in [yukuan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38712043/1426227). However, the following solution uses only the [JAX-RS Client API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/package-summary.html). In theory, it should work with other JAX-RS implementations too:

```java
TrustManager[] trustManager = new X509TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {

    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {

    }
}};

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
sslContext.init(null, trustManager, null);

Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(sslContext).build();
```

---

<sup>**Note 1:** At the time of writing, the standard solution described above won't work with RESTEasy. RESTEasy delegates HTTP calls to [`HttpClient`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) from the Apache HttpComponents project. To trust all certificates with RESTEasy, the [`HttpClient`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) must be customized. For more details, have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38616401/1426227).</sup>

<sup>**Note 2:** You may find [`https://badssl.com`](https://badssl.com/) a useful resource to test clients against bad SSL configs.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.xxxxxxx.rest;

import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;

import org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder;

public class RestClient {

    private Client client;

    public RestClient(Properties properties) {
        super();
        ClientBuilder clientBuilder = new JerseyClientBuilder();
        SSLContext sslContext = null;
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new X509TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        } };
        try {
            sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, null);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
        }
        clientBuilder.sslContext(sslContext);
        client = clientBuilder.build();
    }

    public <T> T execRequest(String uri, Class<T> type) {
        return client.target(uri).request().get(type);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just in case I would forget in the future.

Comment: What is it different from [my approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38716473/1426227)?

Comment: Obviously I don't check my SO very often LOL and it's no different from your approach, just 4 and half hours earlier(same minute i posted my question and only for the purpose of a personal reminder)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than attempting to ignore the error it is much preferable to avoid it in the first place. Adding code as a workaround is risky because anecdotal experiences suggest the code will eventually end up in production.

For development purposes you should create a suitable trust store such that your development certificate is trusted. The accepted answer for [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893819/telling-java-to-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificate) documents how to create such a trust store for such a scenario. If you have the server certificate to hand, which you almost certainly will, you can avoid the browser step and script everything.

Ideally this gets baked into to a process that fails noisily if the certificate cannot be found (such that you don't accidentally deploy a development certificate configuration to a production machine).